# t find bundle for base name org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.i18n.PersistenceUnitLoadingExceptionResource, locale en_US

Tags: tomcat, persistence, eclipselink

I have a problem running an application in Tomcat, it keeps showing this error.

Any assistance to rectify it would be high appreciated.

BR

Ope

2013-02-11 10:38:57,932 ERROR [com.nfi.util.LoggingUtil] - (NonTranAlertJPA.java:30)
        at com.nfialert.nta.BAL.ClusterAlertService.StartOnlineService(ClusterAlertService.java:73)
        at com.nfialert.nta.BAL.ClusterAlertService.run(ClusterAlertService.java:53)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a tomcat issue.

The exception occurs within the `com.nfialert.nta.BAL.ClusterAlertService` class. Ask the vendor of this class.